# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information class not supported on Windows Phone?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I was trying to make use of UBound and LBound function in my Windows Phone 8 app. But I am not able to use Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information class in my application.

I checked in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and found that it is supported for Silverlight, but no information about Windows phone is given.

Where I might have gone wrong? If it is not supported, what's the work around to use UBound and LBound methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UBound and LBound are remnants of Visual Basic 6. Simply use their .NET equivalents:

```
UBound -> array.GetUpperBound(0)
LBound -> array.GetLowerBound(0)
```